# is it possible to call a shell or external command from within :s search and replace command?

Tags: neovim

For example, say I have the following string:

```
my_url = "http://somewebsite.com"
```

and I want to use a regex to replace the url with a version from a url shortener. I've written a command line script, "url_shortener", that takes a url as an input and returns the shortened version.

Is there any way to call something like:

```
:s/\(http[^"]\+\)/system(url_shortener \1)/g
```

This is for vim or neovim

Comment: See `:help sub-replace-\=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
:s/\(http[^"]\+\)/\=system('url_shortener ' . submatch(1))/g
```

If you use `\=` the following expression is evaluated and used for the substitution.

Comment: seems close, but how do you pass the first match to system? It seems system would be unaware of the regex match.

Comment: Also, system seems to require a string argument, e.g. system("echo hello")

Comment: I have corrected the solution :-/ I wrote on my sofa when I wake up, sorry for that :-)

Comment: wow. very nice. thank you!!